# If we have the fixed field $K^H$ and we consider the orbit of an element $\beta_1$, is there an associated group action?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, group-actions

From Artin Algebra section 16.5 Fixed Fields:
[image]

The orbit of the element $\beta_1 \in K$ is being considered.

**Since we are looking at the automorphisms of $K$ and the orbit of some element, is there an associated group action on $K$?**

Comment: Well $H$ acts on $K$ as $g\cdot x = g(x)$, the canonical group action of an automorphism group

Comment: @Max Do you mean the automorphism group of $K$ acts on $K$?

Comment: @Max Or, in this case, the subgroup $H$ of the automorphism group acts on $K$?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I mean